# angular Js DOMStringMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

var $input = $(input); is giving me this object from input

```
jQuery.fn.init[1]
0:input.input-misc-fee.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched
context:input.input-misc-fee.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched
length:1
```

How we can achieve in angular js?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? There is some ways, and it depends on what you want to do.
You can use a directive or simply ```angular.element(".selector")```

Comment: I have list of checkbox using ng-repeat 
angular.element('input.input-misc-fee:checked').data(),
this will give me always data of first checkbox, In case of multiple checkbox ,
How can i get updated values?